# Modelling Funnel data with a regression approach

Tags: regression, marketing

I have the following marketing dataset:

Two years of weekly brand from the YouGov BrandIndex, based on a survey. It includes

Awareness
Consideration
Purchase Intent
Sales

Media Invest into Channel 1 (TV)
Media Invest into Channel 2 (Radio)

per week and per brand.

[image]

My research question is how the channels moderate the effect of one funnel-step to the next.

Awareness → Consideration  Purchase Intent → Sales

Each arrow is moderated by Channel 1 and Channel 2.

What I have done so far is to set up three separate linear, hierarchical models to account for the individual brands and see the moderating effects. So far, so good. One for Awareness and Consideration, one for Consideration and Purchase Intent etc.

Now I want to expand the question and analyse the funnel holistically. Is there a meaningful way to include all the data in one model and keep the (theoretically derived) order of effects and account for the differences between the brands?

Thanks in advance and best,
Felix

Edit: description of channels and source of data, snippet of data included

Comment: You should specify what the unit of analysis is for your 'weekly brand data', e.g., Nielsen market, grocery store sales, household panel data, etc., and describe the channels. Also, depending on the prominence of the brand, *awareness* is frequently high enough to render it moot as a starting level for an HLM. Also, the marketing funnel tracks the *fall off* in consumers from one level to the next, so that by the time you reach the *sales* or loyalty level, you're talking about a fraction of the starting sample, selection bias is the result. Why wouldn't a discrete choice model work? Browse CV

Comment: So, the unit of analysis is the customer tracked over 2 years? Sounds pretty questionable as to whether or not the YouGov BrandIndex is really delivering on that ambitious panel survey design. Again, a discrete choice model would be the way to go. Lots of CV links on this subject. The basic idea is that, for each level of the funnel, you stack up a complete set of customers and indicate with a 0,1 dummy variable their choice at the level of the funnel. That dummy is now your dependent variable and it is conditional on the available predictors in a logistic regression.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the info, that has been helpful already. The data is not exactly as you described, it is brand data, sorry for being uncelar. So I have two years (per week) for each brand, yielding Panel data with the four variables mentioned above, the data is given in percentage. Not so sure if dummy coding is applicable then?

Comment: Ugh! It's aggregated information? That is very hard to work with since you don't know who converted at each stage of the funnel. Would you be able to provide a sample of the data?

Comment: Yes, exactly, it is aggregated, which indeed makes it a bit more challenging. What I am interested to see is how the brand moves through the funnel, driven by the media channels. I have uploaded an except from the dataset for five brands, you can find it here:
https://we.tl/t-t3SNgtxGdQ
It contains the funnel data as well as the advertising spends for TV and Radio.

Comment: Apologies but I browse in private model. Downloading this file would force me to reveal sensitive information. Why not try splicing in a snippet of data for a single brand and a few time periods into the field for your question above? That approach has worked for countless CV queries.

Comment: I am realy interested in the results of the seprate regression model of each KPI for each brand with such data structure, anyway since your question is "is there a meaningful way to include all the data in one model and keep the (theoretically derived) " i would suggest multi level-Markov chain models or mutlilevel-SEM, if your brands do not belong to the same sector think of 3 levels models